# Copy raw contact Android to my app's Account. Contacts duplicated in Android Contacts app

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contacts, android-contacts

Please help me this question. 
I am trying copy all contacts from other accounts to my app's Account. So, I copy all Raw Contacts that does not belong to my app's account to my app's account. And I set the RawContacts.CONTACT_ID to the same as the copied one to avoid duplicate in Android Contacts app. It mean that RawContacts._ID will be different but RawContacts.CONTACT_ID should be the same.

```js
   protected Builder buildEntry(ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder, Resource resource) {
        Contact contact = (Contact) resource;
        EntriesFields entry = getEntriesField(resource);

            builder = builder
                    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
                    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)
                    .withValue(entry.entryColumnRemoteName(), contact.getName())
                    .withValue(entry.entryColumnUID(), contact.getUid())
                    .withValue(entry.entryColumnUnknow(), contact.getUnknownProperties())

                    .withValue(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, contact.getContactId())
                    
                    .withValue(entry.entryColumnDirty(), 1);
    }
}
```

But I am facing these problems :

1. With contacts does not belong to visible group ("Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP" != 1), I can't set the same RawContacts.CONTACT_ID from the source contact to the new one.
2. With some special Contacts even they are in IN_VISIBLE_GROUP, but It is duplicate in Android Contact's app too (it mean that setting RawContacts.CONTACT_ID does not work).

Have you ever faced those problem, and any hint will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you duplicating data in the first place?

Comment: Because I want to support user sync their Contacts (from other Account) to my server.

Comment: To sync to your server, you only need to read data. You shouldn't be writing anything at all if you just want to sync existing data to a server.

Comment: Hi. It's about Syncing, I have a Contacts Sync Adapter. https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html
If user edit contact in Client it will sync to server and reverse if edit in server it will be synced to Client. After copy step, I will sync those of copied contacts with my server.

Comment: Seems, you do not understand the purpose and mechanism behind address book content provider. You are supposed to use own custom account only to store *your own data* in address book. If you don't have your own data to store, don't write anything there.

Comment: Hi @user1643723. thanks for the comment. Currently, my app sync contacts with my server (A web system, with existing contacts). So, we think it's a good idea if we let user copy existing Contacts from Android device to our server too. That why I want to copy contact from other Accounts to my Account in Android, and they will sync to our server over my Contacts Sync Adapter.